# Maximum of the sum of two functions with different variables

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f(x,y) = g(x)+h(y)
$$
with $g$ and $h$ real functions (i.e. they map to the reals). Is it then true that $\max(f) = \max(g) + \max(h)$ as long as the maxima exist for all functions and $(\max(g), \max(h))\in Dom(f)$?

EDIT:

I am gonna write again the question but in a different way because I can see why it is confusing (I read it again and I didn't understand it completely myself) and also why I wanted to know this.

Let $f,g,h$ be as above, and let $z^*, x^*, y^*$ be such that $\max(f) =  f(z^*)$, $\max(g) =  g(x^*)$ and $\max(h) =  h(y^*)$. Given the answers, it follows that
$$
f(z^*) = g(x^*) + h(y^*)
$$
but is it also true that $z^* = (x^*, y^*)$?

This question comes from a much simpler answer in which I want to maximize a function of the form $f(p, \pmb{\theta}) = f_1(p) + f_2(\pmb{\theta})$ where $f$ is a density function, $p$ is a scalar and $\pmb{\theta}$ a vector. I maximized $f_1$ and $f_2$ separately and found $p^*$ and $\pmb{\theta}^*$ maximum of their own functions, but is $(p^*,\pmb{\theta}^*)$ also the maximum of $f$? I believe it is true given the definition of maximum, but I wanted to know if there is a general result or theorem regarding this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume all maxima for $f,g,h$ exist, the result is straightforward.

Denote the maximum value the functions attain as $F, G, H$. Clearly $g(x) \leq G$ and $h(y) \leq H$ for any $x, y$. Thus $g(x) + h(y) \leq G + H$ for all $x,y$ too. Therefore $G+H$ is an upper bound of $f$, since $f(x,y) = g(x) + h(y)$. But since we assumed all functions attain maxima, we know that $g$ and $h$ attain their maxima at values say $x_g, y_g$ respectively. $f$ is well defined for these two values, and we see $$f(x_g,y_g) = g(x_g) + h(y_g) = G + H$$

But then $G+H$ is an upper bound that is attained over $f$, so $G+H$ is the maximum of $f$.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I was under the impression that by "maxima existing" they meant that the maximums were finite real values, not that the functions actually achieved their maximum. Of course that's just semantics, so if so then this is a better approach to the first part.

Comment: @Alex Hmm that's a good point actually. I took it to mean they assumed the maximums were reach, but I see what you mean now. I suppose OP will need to clarify!

Answer (score 1):

First, assume that $g$ and $h$ achieve their maximum values at some points $x_h\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and $y_g\in\mathbb{R^m}$. It makes more sense to ask if $(x_h,y_g)\in Dom(f)$ instead, as $max(h)$, and $max(g)$ are in $\mathbb{R}$ (if they are bounded at least), so $(max(h),max(g))\in\mathbb{R^2}$, not necessarily $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, the domain of $f$. Even if the domain lines up, we would still probably want to consider inputs that could potentially output maximum values for $f$, not inputs only related to the maximum values of $h$ and $g$.

Now, the answer is, basically, yes, but you should check that the definition of maximum is taken explicitly over values of $h$ and $g$, and not the absolute values of the functions. If so, we may take sequences in $\mathbb{R^m}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that the image sequences of $h$ and $g$ converge to $max(h)$ and $max(g)$. Then we can construct a corresponding sequence in $\mathbb{R^{m+n}}$ in which the outputs of $f$ converge to $max(h)+max(g)$. Also, observe that for all points $(x,y)$, $f(x,y)=h(x)+g(y)\leq max(h)+max(g)$, so $max(f)=max(h)+max(g)$.

However, if the maximum is defined as the least upper bound of the the range of the absolute values of each function, then this does not work. Try constructing some $h$ always negative and some $g$ always positive. Then their maximums will both be positive, but you will notice $max(f)\leq max(max(h),max(g))$.